# Multiple Image Uploads with rails_admin (Attachment_fu, Carrierwave, etc.)? Any solutions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave, attachment-fu, rails-admin

I'm looking for a easy way to have multiple attachments on one model using Rails Admin. I've already Paperclip working, but I need multiple images and not just one.

Any hints / ideas / links?

Thank you very much!

Ole

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say that you have a user who wants many photos:

```
class User
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image
  #or
  mount :image, ImageUploader
end
```

So you don't ask your carrierwave or paperclip model to have multiple files, you instead have many paperclip models belonging to your rails model.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I would still prefer being able to upload multiple Images at once using Rails Admin, but it's ok for now.